# How to run a server (a process) for the duration of integration tests?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-tokio

My problem is that server process doesn't get shut down after the last integration test.

In `integration.rs`, I have:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref SERVER: Arc<Mutex<duct::ReaderHandle>> = {
        println!("Starting server");
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(
            cmd!("cargo", "run", "--", "13000")
                .reader()
                .expect("Valid server"),
        ))
    };
}

async fn wait_for_server() {
    lazy_static::initialize(&SERVER);
    // Code to wait
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn integration_test_query_amount() -> Result<()> {
    wait_for_server().await;
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    // Etc...
}
```

The tests work, but the server stays running after the `cargo test` invocation finishes. Is there a nice recipe for starting up *and shutting down* a server like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `Drop` wrapper for a process which will kill it when it goes out of scope. Something along the lines of:

```
struct KillOnDrop(std::process::Child);

impl Drop for KillOnDrop {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.0.kill()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as it looks like you're using `tokio` already, `tokio::process` [supports this out of the box](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/process/struct.Command.html#method.kill_on_drop).

Comment: Statics aren't (necessarily) fully dropped on process exit - so results using this solution can vary - for example, running tests from `rustanalyzer` does result in the server(s) being stopped. running with `cargo test` does not (in my experience) - I still haven't found a reliable solution to this.